# Standard RGB colours in matlab 2016 plots

Tags: matlab, plot

**Problem**

I would like to know the RGB codes of the standard matlab plot colours for `plotyy`, left axis being blueish and right orangish.
Does anyone know the exact codes or is there a way to see them within Matlab ?

This seems like an easy question to me, but I can't figure it out, so help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find this out from the axes properties:

```
ax = plotyy ( [1:10], [1:10], [1:10], [1:10]+3 );
ax(1).YColor   % left hand axis
ax(2).YColor   % right hand axis
```

Comment: If of interest for anyone: the actual triplets are left: [0, 0.4470, 0.7410] and right side [0.8500, 0.3250, 0.0980] for Matlab R2016a.

Comment: Since I dont want to open another question regarding this topic, a short and again super simple question I assume. How do I transfer the Matlab RGB triplet which is in dezimals into the typical RGB between 0 and 255? Cheers!